# SendPhoto method in telegram doesnt work

Tags: php, curl, telegram

I want to `SendPhoto` in my localhost by a `webhook`.  The picture is not in telegram server.  So I need to upload it by multipart header.

**Attempted Code:**

```
$file=fopen("Untitled.png","rb");
$cont=fread($file,filesize("Untitled.png"));
$headers=array("Content-type: multipart/form-data");
$postfields = array("chat_id" => "108432389", "photo" => "$file");
$ch = curl_init();
$options = array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.telegram.org/bot(Token)/SendPhoto",
    CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postfields,
    CURLOPT_INFILESIZE => filesize("Untitled.png"),
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers
);
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
curl_exec($ch);
```

But it can't SendPhoto.

I've looked on different websites for a solution however their code is the same as my code.

Why isn't this working?

Comment: I think this solution might solve your problem  help http://stackoverflow.com/a/32844167/5348805

Answer (score 1):

Here is my PHP function which does the job.

```
sendPicture($id, "picture.png");


function sendPicture($_chatID, $file_on_server){

    $target_url = 'https://api.telegram.org/**<YOUR TOKEN HERE>**/sendphoto';

    $file_name_with_full_path = realpath('./'.$file_on_server);

    $post = array(
        'chat_id'   => $_chatID,
        'photo'     => '@'.$file_name_with_full_path
    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$target_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    $result=curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
    echo $result;


}
```

Comment: Thank you @Markus but it can't sendphoto too.
`{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Error: Bad Request: Wrong persistent file_id specified: contains wrong characters or have wrong length"}`

Comment: @Alireza: seems to me lika a problem with coding of request. Telegram bot API uses UTF-8 only. So you could give this a try, to set your coding to UTF-8: iconv(mb_detect_encoding($text, mb_detect_order(), true), "UTF-8", $text);

Comment: the photo is not in telegram server.
We should upload it first. but we didn't !

Comment: my code posts the image from my webserver to the telegram server. i can see the event in getUpdates. picture becomes a unique id.

Comment: I mean the picture is in our server
First we should send it by a Mulitparat/data-file header i think