# Telegram BOT, send message with gif attachment

Tags: php, bots, telegram

I used this code to send image via BOT found here https://stackoverflow.com/a/32296353/6017365, all work great:

```
$bot_url    = "https://api.telegram.org/bot<bot_id>/";
$url        = $bot_url . "sendPhoto?chat_id=" . $chat_id ;

$post_fields = array('chat_id'   => $chat_id,
    'photo'     => new CURLFile(realpath("/path/to/image.png"))
);

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "Content-Type:multipart/form-data"
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields); 
$output = curl_exec($ch);
```

Then I modified it to send gif with `sendVideo` and `video` parameters.

Now i'd like to edit file to send normal text with gif as attachment....I tried to add `text` parameters in the array, but only image is received...
Any suggest?

Comment: Try using `caption` instead of `text` (text is for text message & caption is for photos and videos & photo albums)

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify @AliKhalili's response;

[sendVideo](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendvideo) accepts a *optional* parameter called `caption` to add some text to a video.

Unlike [sendMessage](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendMessage) that used the *required* `text` field.