# Send Photo uploaded in folder to Telegram BOT

Tags: php

I have an code PHP it saved the uploaded photo from input file

```
<input type="hidden" name="image" class="image-tag">
```

when user uploading any picture it stored to folder support_DATA/

need to send Photo that is stored support_DATA/ to telegram immediately

My PHP Code

```
<?php

$img = $_POST['image'];
$folderPath = "support_DATA/";

$image_parts = explode(";base64,", $img);
$image_type_aux = explode("image/", $image_parts[0]);
$image_type = $image_type_aux[1];

$image_base64 = base64_decode($image_parts[1]);
$fileName = uniqid() . '.png';

$file = $folderPath . $fileName;
file_put_contents($file, $image_base64);

print_r($fileName);
```

?>

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

[See posting a picture to telegram](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32457290/3006405)

```
<?php

$img = $_POST['image'];
$folderPath = "support_DATA/";

$image_parts = explode(";base64,", $img);
$image_type_aux = explode("image/", $image_parts[0]);
$image_type = $image_type_aux[1];

$image_base64 = base64_decode($image_parts[1]);
$fileName = uniqid() . '.png';

$file = $folderPath . $fileName;
file_put_contents($file, $image_base64);

$bot_url    = "https://api.telegram.org/bot<bot_id>/";
$url        = $bot_url . "sendPhoto?chat_id=" . $chat_id ;

$post_fields = array('chat_id'   => $chat_id,
    'photo'     => new CURLFile($file)
);

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "Content-Type:multipart/form-data"
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields); 
$output = curl_exec($ch);

print_r($fileName);
```

Comment: Hi @ulusanyazilim i appreciate your help i tried this code it didnt work for me changed bot_id here $bot_url    = "https://api.telegram.org/bot<bot_id>/"; and chat_id here  array('chat_id' nothing worked just many error

Comment: Did you install the bot?

Sample

url=https://example.com/mypage.php
id=123456789
secret=abcdefghijklmnoprstuvyz

visit url list:
https://api.telegram.org/bot123456789:abcdefghijklmnoprstuvyz/getUpdates
https://api.telegram.org/bot123456789:abcdefghijklmnoprstuvyz/setwebhook?url=https://example.com/mypage.php